The language of creation in Genesis and Job
Community
Do those who understand Genesis 1 as describing a literal six-day creation read Job 38 in the same sort of way? And if not, why not? Nobody that I am aware of reads Job 38 literally, for the simple reason that we understand it to be poetry. We get how metaphors and similes work. So my question is, if we’re willing to make allowances for poetic form in Job, why not Genesis? What in Scripture demands a literal reading of Genesis 1 other than one’s belief and or interpretation.

This question (actually there are four) would be much clearer if you were to quote from Job 38 and to explain what it is that you are referencing. As it is, the question (as well as being a multiple) lacks clarity and detail. You seem to leave the reader to work out your argument for themselves, instead of, yourself, fully citing the argument from Job.

It's an interesting question but I agree with @NigelJ that it needs work. In any case thanks to Jeff for making me think... what IS the creation account in Job 38. Something like this? - “ God laid the foundation of the earth and determined its measurements. He stretched the line upon it and sunk its bases; laid its cornerstone. Then the morning stars sang together  and all the heavenly beings shouted for joy!" (etc.) Thanks again, and please take Nigel's advice.

I added the "creation" tag to the OP.

This feels like more of an argument than a hermeneutical inquiry - as it's phrased it's more of a "don't you agree with me?" than asking others to exegete the text. And as to whether we can/should/could transfer genre from one text by one author to another text of a different author seems very 'opinion based' to me.

One of our topics here is described in "creation" tag: "The creation of the world, described most prominently in Genesis 1-2; other creation traditions are scattered throughout the Hebrew Bible." That being the case, I think this is an appropriate question even though it could be clearer.
To clarify, the basic creation story in Job 38 is found in vss. 4-11

“Where were you when I laid the foundation of the earth?
Tell me, if you have understanding. 5 Who determined its measurements—surely you know!
Or who stretched the line upon it? 6 On what were its bases sunk,
or who laid its cornerstone 7 when the morning stars sang together
and all the heavenly beings shouted for joy? 8 “Or who shut in the sea with doors
when it burst out from the womb, 9 when I made the clouds its garment
and thick darkness its swaddling band, 10 and prescribed bounds for it,
and set bars and doors, 11 and said, ‘Thus far shall you come and no farther,
and here shall your proud waves be stopped’?

Rephrasing this as declarative statements rather than questions we might read:

“Before an human being existed, the LORD God laid the foundation of the earth and  determined its
measurements. He stretched the line upon it and sunk its bases in
the deep. He laid its cornerstone of the earth. Then the morning stars sang
together and all the heavenly beings shouted for joy!
Next God shut in the sea with doors when it burst out from the womb.
He  made the clouds its garment and thick darkness its swaddling band,
10 and prescribed bounds for it, and set bars and doors. Then God
said, ‘Thus far shall you come and no farther,  and here shall your
proud waves be stopped.

The OP asks: "why is denying the literal truth of Job 38 any different from denying the literal truth of Genesis 1?" I would say there are two basic reasons:

It is placed in a relatively obscure position in the canon rather
than at the very beginning where it is clearly meant to be
definitive.

It is phrased as challenges from God to Job not declarative statements. So (as the OP mentioned) it meant to emphasize that God's majesty is
beyond human comprehension.


The OP goes on to say " The only way God can begin to help us understand it is through metaphor, simile, and illustrations drawn from our human experience.  So, if that is true in Job, why are we so suspicious of the idea that He might have done the same with Genesis?"
Answer: Both Job 38 and Genesis 1 (as well as Gen. 2) may involve metaphorical and/or mythic descriptions. It is up to the reader to discern which phrases are meant literally and which are not.

The Hebrew literary form characteristic of poetry is present in Job 38, but not in Genesis 1.  Genesis 1 is instead a prose summary listed by day, much as we would say of the Olympics: on the first day so and so won the gold for such and such, on the second day...   Except apparently God thought we would doubt that "day" means day, so he gives us that definition over and over again: and it was evening and it was morning , the xth day.
(I used to assume that Genesis 1 was poetry, but discovered that I had been misled, and realize that instead of trying to reinterpret scripture based on current scientific theories, I needed to realize that popular science just hadn't gotten all the facts yet, and just believe what God said, and wait for science to catch up.)

Whether prose or poetry, it seem to me that statements like "darkness covered the face of the deep, while a wind from God[b] swept over the face of the waters. 3 Then God said, “Let there be light..." is no less mythic than Job's description of God laying the foundations of the earth while the morning stars sing out for joy."

I’ve met sincere Christians who thought that the "days" were metaphors for ages.  But I think the "evening and morning" phrase invalidates that.  But I don’t think that is high on the list for important issues.  Believing in evolution vs. believing in creation, contrary to the arguments of some, does NOT make a doctor more or less qualified for his job.  It's even less pertinent for lawyers, cooks, software engineers, etc.

The Genesis account has the characteristics of a narrative and a poetic work. Genesis 1 and Genesis 2 (different creation order) are arranged to make a theological statement about the nature of reality.
The seas, the land, and the skies become metaphors used throughout the Bible. The waters as destruction and passing through it, salvation. Separating them exposes land where man can dwell (day 3). The skies (heavens) are where the Elohim (spiritual beings) dwell.
The biblical narrative is hope that we can one day restore the connection of heaven and earth:

Revelation 21:1 (NIV): “Then I saw a new heaven and a new earth, for
the first heaven and the first earth had passed away, and there was no
longer any sea.”

